# Linux Subsystem for Windows: Atom and Visual Studio Code close immediately

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, x-server, atom-editor, visual-studio-code

There is a couple of guides out there on how to get GUI applications running in Linux Subsystem for Windows (WSL).

I tried to follow a handful of them, but each of them had something in common: Both Linux native Github Atom and Linux native Visual Studio Code refused to open.

In my last approach, following [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/261575/how-to-run-graphical-linux-desktop-applications-from-windows-10s-bash-shell/) overly simple guide, I don't get any error messages. Running `atom` or `code` just doesn't do anything and instantly returns.

To put that into perspective, running `gvim` works without a problem:

[image]

What could be the issue here?

**Edit:**
Some details:

- I am using Windows 10 Pro build 17134. (I am not able to join Insiders).
- I am using the default Ubuntu distribution for WSL.
- I tried using xfce4, but got the following error when trying to start Atom:

`assertion 'pthread_mutex_unlock(&m->mutex) == 0' failed at pulsecore/mutex-posix.c:108, function pa_mutex_unlock(). aborting.`

This could be resolved when running `sudo apt remove --purge libpulse0` but `xfce4` depends on it.

Or one could use Windows 10 build 17627 which was never released as far as I can tell.

So in my latest test I am not using any desktop environment, but instead start the applications directly into `DISPLAY=:0.0` so Xming could pick it up, which it does for `gvim`. (I am using `LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1` too)

**Edit 2:**

I tried 18.04, using latest Atom release and both with and without xfce4. Neither was successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Installation:**

  - **Atom:** Download Atom DEB package from [GitHub: Atom releases](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases). Install it with `dpkg -i /path/to/atom-amd64.deb` command. If there is any dependency error install those packages with `apt-get install -f` command ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159114)).
  - **VS Code:** Download Visual Studio Code DEB package from [VScode link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=linux64_deb). Install it with `dpkg -i /path/to/code_amd64.deb` command. If there is any error with `libgtk-x11-2.0` library install it with `apt install libgtk2.0-0` command ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/836144)).
- **Configure X server:** Download [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) and install it. Execute `xlaunch.exe` with default settings (Display Number `-1`or `0`). Add the following environment variables to your .bashrc:

  - `export DISPLAY=:0` (`echo 'export DISPLAY=:0' >> ~/.bashrc`).
  - `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1` (`echo 'export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1' >> ~/.bashrc`)
- **Execute Atom/VSCode**: Type `atom` to execute Atom text editor or `code` to execute VS Code.
- **Notes:** Install only 64bit binaries because WSL is now only available in 64bit Windows OS. Don't run with root user. Always run `apt update` and `apt upgrade` before and after installation. These installations are not dependent on the desktop environments, so that is optional. Long live open-source.

Comment: Except for using Xming instead of VcXserv that is exactly what I did in the first place.